# Application to indicate if multiple image files have Exif data, and delete that data

Tags: windows, images, privacy, exif, jpg

I am looking for a Windows application that will indicate if 1 or more images (JPG/JPEG, typically) have [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data stored in them, and provide an option to delete that data.

The perfect example of such an application is [Easy Exif Delete](http://www.easyexifdelete.com), which has been around for over a decade (and not updated in almost as long!).  Here is its entire user interface:

[image: Screenshot of EasyExifDelete]
*Source: http://www.easyexifdelete.com*

This application does exactly what I want, except that it is missing two key features:

1. Ability to drag-and-drop to add files/folders
2. Ability to use command-line parameters to specify files/folders

Please recommend an application that meets all the above requirements.

*Gratis*, *open-source*, and *portable* are all strongly preferred, but none are required.

Comment: What about RAW files? Do you have any idea what will happen if you remove EXIF data from RAW?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Good questions.  Support for RAW files would be a bonus, but definitely not required.  I don't know if most RAW files contain Exif data or not, or what would happen if it is removed from them.  I would expect the actual sensor data to be untouched, which would be of primary importance, but I could see the removing of certain Exif fields *possibly* making it more difficult to create a desired JPEG file from the RAW data.

Answer (score 1):

This recommendation do not cover 100% of your requirements (it is mostly visual instrument) but you can give it a try.

What I would like to recommend is [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/). Or you can use XnConvert from the same web site. The workflow is relatively sample

- open the software in explorer mode (apply only for XnView MP)
- select images (apply only for XnView MP)
- Tools->Batch Convert (Ctrl+U) (apply only for XnView MP)
- In tab Input you can add images and directories via drag-and-drop or
  via dedicated buttons

[image]

- In tab Actions you add "Clean metadata" and select desired metadata
  to be cleaned up.

[image]

- In Output tab you can select target folder, filename rename and so on
- And press Convert to do the job

**N.B.** When deal with RAW files **DO NOT** touch any of the meta information. Otherwise you will loose integrity of the files and some software may refuse to open them, you will have problem edit, render them to JPG because the software will not know how to deal with the raw information from the sensor.

Comment: Thank you Romeo.  I've used XnView and XnView MP over the years, and wasn't aware of this specific functionality.  I'm going to follow your instructions and take a closer look at XnView MP.  Thank you again.